# POI's Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, garbage-collection, apache-poi

Using `XSSFWorkbook`, I keep getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`, when trying to generate an XLSX file with more than 2.5 million rows.

Besides, I included JVM arguments **-Xms1024M** and **-Xmx6144** with no success.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowID);
    for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
        value = (String) rs.getString(column + 1);
        cell = row.createCell(column);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        spreadsheet.setColumnWidth(column, COLUMN_WIDTH);
        formatedValue = Engine.formatInput(colNames.get(column),value);
        if (formatedValue instanceof Calendar) {
            cell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
            cell.setCellValue((Calendar) formatedValue);
        } else {
            if (formatedValue instanceof Double) {
                cell.setCellValue((Double) formatedValue);
            } else {
                if (formatedValue instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) formatedValue);
                } else {
                    if (formatedValue instanceof String) {
                        cell.setCellValue((String) formatedValue);
                    } else {
                        /*
                         * Unreachable.
                         */
                        cell.setCellValue(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    rowID++;
    if (this.isMaxSpreadsheetRowsReached(rowID)) {
        newSpreadSheet(rsmd, numberOfColumns, styleEntete);
        rowID = 1;
    }
}
```

The exception occurs within the inner-for-loop.

One workaround was to use `SXSSFWorkbook`, but, still, I want to work with `XSSFWorkbook`.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Please post the code where this error is occurring

Comment: @Mathyou, question updated.

Answer (score 1):

You have answered your own question. Your source seems to be streamed (rs.next()), while the generated Workbook is stored in Memory. There are a lot of internal object references within the spreadsheet object, which apparrently leads to a complex garbage collector overhead.

To avoid this, use the streaming verison of XSSFWorkbook (SXSSFWorkbook).

But to return to the reason why you probably ask this question/don't want to stream it:
You probably want to keep all registers in memory, so you can update header information (print a total number of registers, an average, or thelike). I am afraight that this kind of operation can't scale indefinetly, and you can either achieve this by running through your source twice (first accumulate all the secondary information, like averages, maxima or minima, then print the content), or by printing all this info on a secondary page, which you can then reference within the first page with an "="-formula, so it looks like the information is on top of the page.

Comment: Isn't it possible to explicitely flush with `XSSFWorkbook`?

Comment: The problem is, that with POI you are usually able to access any row object any time. So if you wanted to flush them, you'd have to ensure that no further access is made on a previous row object. This is what the SXSSFWorkbook basically solves, by only keeping portions of the rows in memory. Excerpt from the java-doc of SXSSFWorkbook:
" This allows to write very large files without running out of memory as only a configurable portion of the rows are kept in memory at any one time."